# How get the Employee Title from Admin Directory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm expecting to get the job title of the user via using google app script, but I'm getting the log print as follows

```
[20-11-17 12:31:35:307 IST] [{title=Manager, department=Marketing, primary=true, customType=}]
```

The below is my code

```
function getUserDirectory(){
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var employee = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).organizations;
Logger.log(employee);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get only the title of the employee. I've tried adding [1] or [2] or [3] after the .orgainizations object but it doesn't work.

What would be the right code to get my answer?

Comment: `employee[0].title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`employee` is a array of objects and contains only 1 object with index `0`. So, use

```
employee[0].title
```